# Rock, paper sciccors working, but not as planned

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code for a simple rock, paper and scissors game.
It works but gives very unexpected results and i can't figure out why.

html:

```
<form action="#" id="form">
<input type="text" id="mypick" placeholder="Rock, paper or scissors?">
<input type="submit" value="Pick" id="button">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var rock = 0,
paper = 1,
scissors = 2;

function result() {
  var computerPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(computerPick);

  var myPick = document.getElementById('mypick');
  if (myPick == "rock") {
    myPick = 0;
  } else if (myPick == "paper") {
    myPick = 1;
  } else {
    myPick = 2;
  }

  if (myPick === computerPick) {
    alert("The same, try again!");
  } else if (myPick === 0 && computerPick === 1) {
    alert("You lose! Computer had paper!");
  } else if (myPick === 0 && computerPick === 2) {
    alert("You win! Computer had scissors!")
  } else if (myPick === 1 && computerPick === 0) {
    alert("You win! Computer had rock")
  } else if (myPick === 1 && computerPick === 2) {
    alert("You lose! Computer had scissors")
  } else if (myPick === 2 && computerPick === 0) {
    alert("You lose! Computer had rock")
  } else if (myPick === 2 && computerPick === 1) {
    alert("You win! Computer had paper")
  }
  document.getElementById('form').reset();
};

document.getElementById("button").onclick = result;
```

Comment: perhaps you have missed the latent Lizzard and Spock variables? kidding. welcome to SO.

Comment: Hey there. First try replacing submit button type with button button type

Comment: `It works but gives very unexpected results` - so, in other words, it doesn't work. Can you expand on what these unexpected results are, or do you expect people to run your code and check results for themselves?

Comment: @imsiso - or remove the form element altogether if you're not even wanting to submit a form

Comment: Man your code is so that it's much as easier to be rewritten than being edited. Need some time

Comment: You need `var myPick = document.getElementById('mypick').value;` - note the `.value` part that you didn't have. (I didn't post this as an answer because I'm confused about why you would say your current code "works" - not sure if there's something else that I'm missing.)

Comment: Here is my answer. I was using smartphone so it took a while to type. (:

Answer (score 1):

You merely *don't* use the true value of `myPick`, because you wrote:

```
var myPick = document.getElementById('mypick');
```

which gets the *element*, not its value. You should instead write:

```
var myPick = document.getElementById('mypick').value;
```

So it works *really*.

Now you could dramatically reduce your code (and at the same time increase reliability and readability).

**EDIT: my best solution**

After posting my first answer (still visible below) I read the @imsiso's one, which gave me the idea for a yet more simple solution.

Some of its improvements are explicitly detailed in my first answer, the others come from the @imsiso's idea to use `<select>` rather than `<input>`, where I added the following changes:

- direct execution on click (no more button)
- no need of checking for bad choice or no choice (only 3 valid choices possible)
- no need of a list of the "weapons" in JS (use innerHTML of the options)
- replace `alert()` by populating a `<p>` with the result, so all the game is one-click

Here it is:

```js
choice.onclick = function() {
  var wins = [0.2, 1.0, 2.1],
      computerPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
      myPick = +choice.value;
  result.innerHTML = myPick == computerPick ?
    'The same, try again!' :
    'You ' +
      (wins.indexOf(myPick + computerPick / 10) == -1 ? 'lose' : 'win') +
      '! Computer had ' + choice[computerPick].innerHTML + '!';
};
```

```html
<select id="choice" style="cursor: pointer;" size="3" multiple autofocus
  title="Click to choose...">
  <option value="0">rock</option>
  <option value="1">paper</option>
  <option value="2">scissors</option>
</select>
<p id="result"></p>
```

---

**My first answer (final version deprecated)**

First replace:

```
var rock = 0,
paper = 1,
scissors = 2;
```

by `var picks = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];`.

Then also replace:

```
  if (myPick == "rock") {
    myPick = 0;
  } else if (myPick == "paper") {
    myPick = 1;
  } else {
    myPick = 2;
  }
```

by this: `myPick = picks.indexOf(myPick);`

and add a 1st control like this:

```
if (myPick == -1) {
  alert('Wrong entry: please enter one of "rock", "paper", or "scissors"!');
  return;
}
```

Finally you can also simplify the way you compute who win, as you can analyze by yourself in the fully working version below:

```js
var picks = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
    wins = [0.2, 1.0, 2.1];

function result() {
  var computerPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(computerPick);

  var myPick = document.getElementById('mypick').value;
  myPick = picks.indexOf(myPick);
  document.getElementById('form').reset();

  if (myPick == -1) {
    alert('Wrong entry: please enter one of "rock", "paper", or "scissors"!');
    return;
  }
  if (myPick === computerPick) {
    alert("The same, try again!");
    return;
  }
  alert('You ' +
    (wins.indexOf(myPick + computerPick / 10) == -1 ? 'lose' : 'win') +
    '! Computer had ' + picks[computerPick] + '!'
  );
};

document.getElementById("button").onclick = result;
```

```html
<form action="#" id="form">
<input type="text" id="mypick" placeholder="Rock, paper or scissors?">
<input type="submit" value="Pick" id="button">
</form>
```

Comment: I liked your algorithm. But you sure your code works? Cause the submit btn will refresh the browser.

Comment: I will give +1 after I found out that your code is working. (:

Comment: @imsiso Sure it works (you can check the code snippet). I must confess I dkdn't pay attention to the (useless) presence of a `<form>` and its `<button type="submit">`. But it doesn't matter, because all the job is done before submitting so it keeps transparent for the user. In the other hand, your solution gave me the idea to use `<select>` like you did: you may look at my edited answer which includes this improvement among others. So I upvote your solution, thanks!

Comment: okay. Thanks. for the time and afford. and the style and including my name in your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code which I think should work. Your mistakes.

If you use submit then your browser will refresh when u click.

And also there is no need to add form tag cause there is not any request sending to server.

And `document.getElementById('mypick')` will return text box as an object. So to get the object's value you should use `document.getElementById('mypick').value`

And what if user types " bla bla" or "Paper" instead of "paper"? Then they will be counted as "rock"

And some other things like using extra ";" or using var to define variables you are gonna use in a function etc.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title> best browser game and ever</title>
<script>
function result(){
  var computerPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(computerPick);
  var strs=["Rock","Paper","Scissors"];

  var myPick = document.getElementById('mypick').value;
  if (myPick==-1){
    alert('chooooose!');
  }else{
    var tmp = myPick - computerPick;
    if (top==0){
      alert("The same, try again!");
    }elseif(top==1 || top==-2){
      alert('You Won! Computer choosed:'+strs[computerPick]);
    }elseif(top==-1 || top==2){
      alert('You Lost! Computer choosed:'+strs[computerPick]);
    }else{alert('something is wrong with universe');}
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you win this, all hour dreams will come true.</p>
<select Id="mypick">
<option value="-1">choose</option>
<option value="0">R</option>
<option value="1">P</option>
<option value="2">S</option>
</select>
<input Id="kill" type="button" value="kill" onclick="result" />
</body>
</HTML>
```